# Anti-quark transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, group-theory, antimatter, quarks, strong-force

The center of $SU(3)$ is $Z_3$. So a quark transforms under an element $z\in Z_3$ in this center as $q\to q'=z q$. How do I figure out how the anti-quark $\bar q$ under this center? How about the octet? I have no clue where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Since antiquarks are in the irrep $(0,1)$ (or $\boldsymbol{\bar{3}}$) which is *conjugate* to quark irrep $(1,0)$, antiquarks will go as
$$
\bar q\to \bar q’=z^* \bar q\,.
$$
Since the octet is $(1,1)$ and obtained from the tensor product $(1,0)\otimes (0,1)=(1,1)\oplus (0,0)$, elements in the octets are the traceless: $q_i \bar q_j$ for $i\ne j$ and $q_i \bar q_i-\frac{1}{3}\left(\sum_k q_k\bar q_k\right)$, where the last sum removes the trace, which is in $(0,0)$.

Comment: Correct, but I'm not sure you made it clear to the OP that the singlet and the octet are 0-triality (singlets under$ Z_3$ )...

Comment: Thank you. Did you mean $z^\dagger \bar q$ instead? Also, what should I expect for the sextet (2,0) or decuplet (3,0)?

Comment: @user176936 The $(2,0)$ is the symmetric part of $(1,0)\otimes(1,0)$.  Likewise for the $(3,0)$.